# remove substring between delimiters FROM LEFT TO RIGHT using regex - C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to use regex to remove a substring from a string, from left to right, meaning that I want the right delimiter to be recognized and then to remove everything until the closest delimiter found on the left (not the other way around, left and right delimiters are different).

An example:

```
string myInput = "This [[ should stay  and [[ this sould go | this should stay ]] as well";
string  myRegex = "\\[\\[(.*?)\\|";
string myOutput = Regex.Replace (myInput, myRegex,"");
```

I want to remove everything from the "|" to the first "[[" to the left, but regex takes everything from the first "[[" in the sentence until the "|".

```
I get: myOutput = "This  this should stay ]] as well"

When what I really want is: "This [[ should stay  and this should stay ]] "
```

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use negation instead of the `.*` token. Also, place your pattern inside a verbatim string literal.

```
string myRegex = @"\[\[[^[|]*\|";
```

<kbd>[**Ideone Demo**](http://ideone.com/oieMSY)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a negative lookahead assertion.

```
myOutput = Regex.Replace(myInput, @"\[\[(?:(?!\[\[).)*?\|", "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/rG1mG8/1)

`(?:(?!\[\[).)*?` would match any character but not of `[[` non-greedily. That is, this will check the condition that the character going to be matched won't be the first character in `[[` . If yes, then it would match the corresponding character else the match would fail since the pattern which actually follows the negative lookahead is `\|` (*matches a literal pipe symbol*) which expects an immediate  following pipe symbol.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, I added a negated character class that will make sure we do not capture the `[` after double `[`:

```
 string myInput = "This [[ should stay  and [[ this sould go | this should stay ]] as well";
 string myRegex = @"\[\[([^\[]*?)\|";
 string myOutput = Regex.Replace(myInput, myRegex, "");
```

Output:

```
This [[ should stay  and  this should stay ]] as well
```

Have a look at a [sample program](http://goo.gl/o7b3I5).